# Does an inertial frame have to be orthogonal?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity, coordinate-systems, vectors, inertial-frames

I got a question in the quiz that does an inertial frame be necessarily orthogonal or it could have non-orthogonal axes? I was wondering about the answer but I couldn't think through. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

You can set up whatever co-ordinate axes you like in an inertial frame of reference (or, indeed, in a non-inertial frame of reference) - orthogonal, non-orthogonal, cylindrical, spherical etc. What makes a frame of reference inertial is the way that the laws of physics work within the frame of reference. Whatever co-ordinate system you then superimpose on the frame of reference is a separate choice.

Answer (score 2):

I think your question actually is: Should the basis vectors of a coordinate system be orthogonal? The answer is no, you can choose the basis vectors in any way you would like. An inertial frame defines the frame of reference of an observer, which in principal does not require a coordinate system.

Comment: I know what you mean, but you can't chose basis vectors in any way you like. They have to be linear independent and span the vector space.

Comment: They have to have no pair collinear.

Comment: True, thanks for correcting me.